# Powershell can't find Invoke-Sqlcmd from a TFS Build

Tags: sql-server, powershell, tfs, tfs-2015

I have a powershell script that is invoked from a Powershell build step in TFS. The powershell script works fine both on my dev PC and the build server when invoked from the command line. The script uses `Invoke-Sqlcmd` to execute some SQL.

However, when the script is executed from the TFS build, it errors with the following:

```
The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

This only occurs from with TFS so I'm having difficulty figuring out how to fix it. How do I get this to work from TFS?

Comment: Do you have the correct PowerShell modules installed on build agent?

Comment: What returns Get-Module ?

Comment: @JodyT yes, `Invoke-Sqlcmd` work when executed from a powershell command prompt on the build server. Just not when the build is triggered from TFS.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean when I run `Get-Module` from a powershell prompt it lists **SQLPS**. When run from inside a script triggered by a TFS build it isn't present. Not even if I use the `-listavailable` switch.

Answer (score 0):

The `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet is part of the **SQLPS Module**.
As the error states, the module is not visible for the scope of the session you are invoking that script from (for some reason). Maybe, just an `Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking` inside the script would make it available.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231286(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Hi, if I run `Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking` from a powershell prompt on the build server (where the agent runs) it appears to work, but when run from inside a script triggered by TFS it fails with this error: `Import-Module : The specified module 'sqlps' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
directory.`